# Fetch API dynamically using react from a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am hoping somebody can help me with what I'm trying to do.

So I'm fetching an API endpoint that returns sets of data which is fine, but what
What I like to do is to use all campaignid parameter values and make an api call one-by-one to retrieve each campaignid value's results so it would use each id from the campaignid and makes an api call, obviously the end point for the other call would be different. Just wondering how do I do that dynamically

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const url = "https://6271dd6bc455a64564b8b6b6.mockapi.io/AP1/REST/Numberofsubmissons";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => {
 
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data))
      
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
   
      <code>{JSON.stringify(data)}</code>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: So the code calls `fetch(url)` and this returns *what* exactly? Is your question how to then take this `data` value and make a bunch of new requests? Can you edit to include a [mcve] for what you are trying to do? What are the subsequent API requests you want to make?

Comment: @DrewReese here's the sandbox i created 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-onclick-forked-y9j5ox?file=/src/App.js 
Based on what is retrieved, use the campaignid value in a separate section on my code to do an api call directly to that unique id to retrieve. Basically, the end point would be like https://XXXX.com/campaignidvalue/  I just dont know how to do that. It should also go through each campaignid one by one like a loop and return the results

Comment: We can already see what that initial response is. What are you trying to use from it for the next batch of requests?

Comment: @DrewReese so taking what is retrieved, and making api calls in a different section using useeffects

https://XXXX.com/campaignidvalue1
https://XXXX.com/campaignidvalue2
https://XXXX.com/campaignidvalue3

Comment: @DrewReese correct use the first response, and make api calls one by one based on each campaignid

Comment: What is the API you are trying to hit? Or is your question a little more general in that you just want to take the `data` response and make another batch of requests? Do you need to keep the `data` in local state, or do you really only need the second fetched data?

Comment: "take the data response and make another batch of requests?" yes
"Do you need to keep the data in local state, or do you really only need the second fetched data?" I need to have the second fetched data, 

So each of these end point will have the "records" parameter that I need to retrieve one by one
https://6271dd6bc455a64564b8b6b6.mockapi.io/AP1/REST/campaigndetail

The first response retrieve all campaignid's then use the response to do multiple calls to get to each and retrieve "records" one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra `useEffect` that listens to `data` changes and then, based on the `campaignid` make several calls to the *different* API with that `campaignid`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      Promise.all(
        data.map(async ({ campaignid }) => {
          const response = await fetch(`${url}/${campaignid}`);
          return await response.json();
        }),
      ).then((res) => { setNewData(res) });
    }
}, [data]);
```

Made some playable code, using some fake promises - the response can be stored as an object with `{ [campaignid]: data }` structure or something similar depends on your needs.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-onclick-forked-o1q36b?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

The first API request returns an array of data that contains `campaignid` values. You can map this fetched `data` array to an array of `fetch` Promises fetching the campaign data by id. The resolved array will have all the fetched data that you can save also into local state.

```
const baseUrl = "https://6271dd6bc455a64564b8b6b6.mockapi.io/AP1/REST/";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [campaignData, setCampaignData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAllData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(baseUrl + "Numberofsubmissons");
        const data = await response.json();

        setData(data); // save data to state

        const campaignDataReqs = data.map(async ({ campaignid }) => {
          const response = await fetch(baseUrl + `campaigndetails/${campaignid}`);
          const campaignData = await response.json();
          return campaignData;
        });

        const campaignData = await Promise.all(campaignDataReqs);

        setCampaignData(campaignData); // save campaign data to state
      } catch(error) {
        // catch and handle any rejected Promises or thrown errors
      }
    };

    fetchAllData();
  }, []);

  return (
    ....
  );
}
```